# php Как сопоставить два массива по id роли и актера и вывести имена

Tags: php, массивы, вывод

Имеется два массива
Актеры и роли
У ролей хранятся id актеров которые их играют
Вот как получаю их id:

```
<?php $prsns_titles = []; ?>
<?php $mdls = $this->_models ?>
<?php $roles = current($mdls)->_elements ?>
<?php $prsns =  current($mdls)->_persons?>
<!-- roles -->
  <?php
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
      var_dump("<pre>", $role->number,"</pre>");
  }
  ?>

  <!-- persons -->
   <?php
   foreach ($prsns as $person) {
       var_dump("<pre>", $person->id,"</pre>");
   }
   ?>
```

Выводится вот это:

```
 string(5) "
"
string(10) "{"0":"79"}"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(10) "{"0":"56"}"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(10) "{"0":"21"}"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(10) "{"0":"18"}"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(10) "{"0":"29"}"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(9) "{"0":"2"}"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(10) "{"0":"20"}"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(9) "{"0":"9"}"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(19) "{"0":"51","1":"88"}"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(9) "{"0":"8"}"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(19) "{"0":"74","1":"76"}"
string(6) "
" -----------Отсюда выводятся уже id актера---------- string(5) "
"
string(1) "9"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(2) "29"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(2) "21"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(2) "20"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(2) "18"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(1) "2"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(1) "8"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(2) "51"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(2) "56"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(2) "74"
string(6) "
" string(5) "
"
string(2) "88"
string(6) "
"
```

Пример вывода роли:

```
[1]=>
  object(stdClass)#212 (14) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "575"
    ["entry"]=>
    string(3) "128"
    ["number"]=>
    string(10) "{"0":"56"}"
    ["title"]=>
    string(14) "УЧИТЕЛЬ"
    ["tone"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tone_image"]=>
    NULL
    ["volume"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["price"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["state"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["checked_out"]=>
    string(2) "42"
    ["checked_out_time"]=>
    string(19) "2021-03-15 21:27:55"
    ["ordering"]=>
    string(3) "575"
    ["featured"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["params"]=>
    object(JRegistry)#200 (1) {
      ["data":protected]=>
      object(stdClass)#198 (0) {
      }
    }
  }
```

Пример вывода актера:

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#239 (19) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["eid"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["cid"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["tid"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["title"]=>
    string(45) "Александр Жук"
    ["alias"]=>
    string(23) "aleksandr-zuk"
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(48) "images/persons/thumbs/AleksandrZuk.jpg"
    ["icon"]=>
    string(47) "images/persons/icons/AleksandrZuk.jpg"
    ["images"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["info"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["description"]=>
    string(312) ""
    ["state"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["checked_out"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["checked_out_time"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["ordering"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["featured"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["params"]=>
    string(92) "{"show_icon":"1","show_link":"1","title_suffix":"","sex":"0","link_to":"","link_to_text":""}"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(25) "9:aleksandr-zuk"
    ["link"]=>
    string(47) "/lyudi-teatra/artisty/9-aleksandr-zuk"
  }
```

Как можно вывести Имя актера и рядом его роль?

Comment: Чем связываются Роли с Актерами? Как это связать на примере тех данных что Вы выложили?

Comment: В ролях хранится id актеров:
string(10) "{"0":"79"}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут все просто, необходимо обойти массив Ролей и составить карту данных Актеров и их Ролей, а во время вывода Актеров уже по этой карте выводить названия ролей.

```
<?php

$roles = [

    (object) [
        'number' => '{"0":"9"}',
        'title'  => 'УЧИТЕЛЬ',
    ],
    (object) [
        'number' => '{"0":"51","1":"88"}',
        'title'  => 'НЕ УЧИТЕЛЬ',
    ],
];


$prsns = [

    (object) [
        'id'    => "9",
        'title' => 'Александр Жук',
    ],
    (object) [
        'id'    => "88",
        'title' => 'Максим Муха',
    ],
];

$roleActors = [];

foreach ($roles as $role) {

    $personIds = json_decode($role->number, true);

    foreach ($personIds as $personId) {

        $roleActors[$personId] = $role->title;

    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($roleActors);
echo "</pre>\n<br>";

foreach ($prsns as $person) {

    print_r("<pre>" . $person->title . " {$roleActors[$person->id]}</pre>");
    echo "\n<br>";

}
```

Пример карты данных сопоставления:

```
Array
(
    [9] => УЧИТЕЛЬ
    [51] => НЕ УЧИТЕЛЬ
    [88] => НЕ УЧИТЕЛЬ
)
```

Итог:

```
Александр Жук УЧИТЕЛЬ

Максим Муха НЕ УЧИТЕЛЬ
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Вы избавили меня от головной боли)